# QgsRubberBand Move Event

Tags: pyqgis, qgsrubberband

I have created a `QgsRubberBand` which copies feature from layer. I need to be able visually move this rubberband on mouse event 'move'. Actually same visualisation like during  `self.iface.actionMoveFeature()`

```
class mMapTool(QgsMapTool):

def __init__(self, mainLayer, canvas):

    self.mlayer = mainLayer
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.active = False
    QgsMapTool.__init__(self, self.canvas)
    self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QGis.Polygon)
    mFillColor = QColor(0, 0, 0, 88);
    self.rubberBand.setColor(mFillColor)
    self.rubberBand.setWidth(2)
    self.reset()


def reset(self):

    self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
    self.isEmittingPoint = False
    self.rubberBand.reset(QGis.Polygon)

def canvasPressEvent(self, e):


    global mdict
    mdict = {}

    if e.button() == 1:
        self.isEmittingPoint = True
        for feature in self.mlayer.selectedFeatures():
            centroid_tuple = (feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x(),
                              feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y())
            mdict[feature.id()] = [centroid_tuple]
            geo = feature.geometry()
            break

        self.rubberBand.addGeometry(geo, None)

def get_canvas_point(self, position):

    x = position.x()
    y = position.y()
    trans = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform()
    return trans.toMapCoordinates(x, y)

def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
    if not self.isEmittingPoint:
        return
    pos = e.pos()
    point = self.get_canvas_point(pos)
    self.rubberBand.movePoint(point)
    self.rubberBand.show()
```

But my current code doesn't work. I tried different options, searched for solution everywhere but it seems like I'm only one with this problem.